# Echoing table attribute value in php

Tags: php

If I have table with some attributes in tr & td:

```
<table>
    <tr class='test'>
        <td align='left'>
            how to echo class value here??
        </td>
        <td align='right'>
            how to echo align value here??
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I echo the value of the attributes and show table like below?

```
|test    |   right|
```

Comment: You have to store the value in a variable, then echo it in both places. If the attribute is arbitrary however, you need javascript.

Comment: would you please give example?

Comment: Question editted. Need your help.

Comment: Answered by @Rahautos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write simple `echo` inside `php` tag :-

```
<td <?php echo "align='left'"; ?> >
<td <?php echo "align='right'"; ?> >
<tr <?php echo "class='test'";?>>
```

Comment: What I need to be shown in the view is only the value of the attributes, in my examples, the table should show like this: |test    |   right|

Comment: <table border="1" style="width:600px">
    <tr class='test'>
        <td align='left'>
            <?php echo 'class' ?>
        </td>
        <td align='right'>
            <?php echo 'align' ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: That will shown like this: |class | align| . What I need is to echo the value and shown like this: |test | right| . I need the way to get the values from the attributes and echo them.

Comment: <table border="1" style="width:600px" >
<tr class='test' id="myId">
<td align='left'>
<?php echo"
<script>
var li = document.getElementById('myId');
document.write(li.className)
</script>"
?>
</td>
<td align='right' id='myId2'>
<?php echo"
<script>
var li = document.getElementById('myId2').getAttribute('align');
document.write(li)
</script>"
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: try this @user2555665

Comment: It works. Appreciate.